# button in iframe should trigger event

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a button in an iframe. I want that button to trigger an event outside the iframe. How can I do that?

I have the following button

```
<button class="btn">Back</button>
```

inside an iframe

I want when people click on that button, that it triggers an event in the view outside of the iframe. How can I do that?

No need to worry about cross domain because the iframe url is on the same domain as the view.

The button only shows up when the user navigates to the second page of the iframe.

Comment: outside the iframe on the same window ? Or in a different window / browser ?

Comment: Do you have control of the page outside, is it the same domain?

Comment: yes the page outside is on the same domain. The iframe loads a page that is not on the same domain and then when people click next, it loads a page on the same domain. On the second page is where the button shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't, at least not directly. Events stop bubbling when they hit the top of the document.

You could do something like:

```
button.addEventListener("click", passEventToParent);

function passEventToParent(event) {
    parent.querySelector("iframe").dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

[See dispatchEvent on MDN for more information about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).